# Updating a book created with iBooks Author

Tags: ios, ibooks, ibook-author

I have a quick question about Apple's iBooks Author:

is it in any way possible to **update** a book created with iBooks Author?

I mean: if I create a book, publish it and users download it, can I change it afterwards so that users get a notification and can download the new version (overwriting the old version)? Similar to how it works with apps?

thanks for the help,
Thomas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is an old question, it should be noted that this is now possible, with iBooks Author 2: you add Version Info as described in this link: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5213

Answer (score 0):

no, that's not an option - you could update your book (republish) but user won't be notified. Also consider that paid publications under ISBN could be subject of new ISBN.
See e.g.:
[iBooks Author updating your book?](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17471154)

Peter